# Volume of a Region defined by Inequalities

Tags: regions, inequalities

I am trying to compute the volume of a 3-dimensional region defined by 5 inequalities. Mathematica takes too long to compute it. In fact, I haven't ever seen it complete the execution of the below code:

```
theta = Pi/5;
dh = 0.5;
din = 1.016;
dout = 1.27;
zz = z * Cos[theta] - x*Sin[theta];
xx = z * Sin[theta] + x*Cos[theta];
yy = y;
region1 = 
z^2 >= (dh/2 + 0.0254)^2 - (dout/2)^2*
x^2/(x^2 + y^2);
region2 = (din/2)^2 < 
x^2 + y^2 < (dout/2)^2;
region3 = -1 <= z <= 1;
region4 = zz^2 <= (dh/2)^2 - (dout/2)^2*
xx^2/(xx^2 + yy^2);
region5 = (din/2)^2 < xx^2 + yy^2 < (dout/2)^2; 
region = ImplicitRegion[{region1, region2, region3, region4, region5}, {x, y, z}];
Volume[region]
```

Any reason why it takes so long (or does not complete)?
Any alternative method to compute the volume (that does not involve discretization)?

EDIT: 
Calculating the volume of even two of the regions similarly takes too long:

```
theta = Pi/5;
dh = 0.5;
din = 1.016;
dout = 1.27;
zz = z * Cos[theta] - x*Sin[theta];
xx = z * Sin[theta] + x*Cos[theta];
yy = y;
regionA = zz^2 <= (dh/2)^2 - (dout/2)^2 * xx^2/(xx^2 + yy^2);
regionB = (din/2)^2 < xx^2 + yy^2 < (dout/2)^2; 
region = ImplicitRegion[{regionA, regionB}, {x, y, z}];
Volume[region]
```

Comment: I do not recommend the use of either `D[]` (the differentiation operator) nor subscripts in your code; consider eliminating them.

Comment: @J.M. Edited. Thanks

Comment: @Feyre But Mathematica must at least show that the volume is zero. I want to compute this for different values of theta, dh, din and dout and not all of them necessarily give zero volume

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: For some reason, it won't discretize the region if region1 is included, but: `r2 = DiscretizeRegion[region, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]` `Volume[r2]` `0.033056`

Comment: @Feyre I tried using just the last two regions and it still does not work. Check my edit. The code is much simpler now

Comment: Are you sure you Discretized the region?

Comment: @Feyre I did not discretize the region. Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 2):

You should discretize your region, taking care to avoid singularities, here I leave out region 1:

```
region = ImplicitRegion[{region2, region3, region4, region5}, {x, y, 
z}];
r2 = DiscretizeRegion[region, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image]

Now you can calculate the volume:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Volume[r2]]
```

> {0.000382, 0.0330559}

Comment: I need to add region1 too. Do you know why it cannot be discretized the way other regions can be?

Comment: @Shivanand All I know is that when region1 and 4 come together, i get an error which is unknown to google. `TriangulateMesh::tmfail: TriangulateMesh failed to triangulate the mesh. >>`

Comment: I know for sure that the intersection is very small. Each region is very important for the final result